# How do I Webscrape a website that uses iframes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website 'https://swimming.org.nz/results.html'. In the form that comes up, I am filling in only the Age column as 8 to 8. I am using the following code to scrape the table as suggested elsewhere in StackOverflow. I am unable to get the table. How to get all the tables for this age group 8 to 8.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://swimming.org.nz/results.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.select_one("x-MS_FIELD_AGE.FROM.L").attrs["src"]
r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for row in soup.select("x-form-text x-form-field"):
    print("\t".join([e.text for e in row.select("th, td")]))
```

Comment: Are your CSS Selectors correct? I don't see an `id` of `detail-displayer` or a class `.history` on the page.

Comment: @MendelG , When I change id to '"x-MS_FIELD_AGE.FROM.L" and class to "x-form-text x-form-field", I still get the same error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'"

Answer (score 1):

You will see that it is not necessary using BeautifulSoup if you' ve look at the developer tools on your browser. Sending request is below and response type is xml. You don't need any scraping tool. You can get all of that data changing the `StartRowIndex`and `MaximumRowCount`.

```
import requests

url = "https://connect.swimming.org.nz/snz-wrap-public/pages/pageRequestHandler?tunnelTarget=tableData%2F%3F&data_file=MS.COMP.RESULTS&dict_file=MS.COMP.RESULTS&doGet=true"

payload="StartRowIndex=0&MaximumRowCount=100&sort=BY-DSND%20COMP.DATE%20BY-DSND%20STAGE&dir=ASC&tid=extTable1620108707767_4352538&selectCriteria=GET-LIST%20CMS_TABLE_19483_65507_076_184811_&extraColumns=%3CColumns%20DynamicLinkRoot%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.swimming.org.nz%3A443%2Fsnz-wrap-public%2Fworkflows%2F%22%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CColumnName%3EExpander%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CField%3EFRAGMENT_DISPLAY.SPLITS%3C%2FField%3E%3CShowInExpander%3Etrue%3C%2FShowInExpander%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CFieldExpression%3E%7BMEMBER.FORE1%7D%20%7BMEMBER.SURNAME%7D%3C%2FFieldExpression%3E%3CField%3EEXPRESSION_FIELD_1%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EName%2520%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E130%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXGENDER%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EGender%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E50%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EENTRANT.AGE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EAge%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E35%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CFieldExpression%3E%7BXCATEGORY2%7D%3C%2FFieldExpression%3E%3CField%3ECATEGORY2.NUM%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EDistance%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E70%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXCATEGORY1%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EStroke%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E70%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CFieldExpression%3E%7BTIME%24%24SNZ%7D%3C%2FFieldExpression%3E%3CField%3ERESULT.TIME.MILLISECONDS%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3ETime%2520%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E70%3C%2FWidth%3E%3CAlign%3Eright%3C%2FAlign%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EFINA.POINTS%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EFINA%2520Points%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E85%3C%2FWidth%3E%3CAlign%3Eright%3C%2FAlign%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EFINA.YEAR%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EPoints%2520Year%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E80%3C%2FWidth%3E%3CAlign%3Eright%3C%2FAlign%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3E%24DATE%24COMP.DATE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EDate%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E70%3C%2FWidth%3E%3CAlign%3Eright%3C%2FAlign%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXEVENT.CODE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EMeet%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E190%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EPARAMETER1%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3ECourse%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3CWidth%3E50%3C%2FWidth%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3C%2FColumns%3E&extraColumnsDownload=%3CDownloadColumns%20DynamicLinkRoot%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.swimming.org.nz%3A443%2Fsnz-wrap-public%2Fworkflows%2F%22%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXGENDER%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EGender%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EENTRANT.AGE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EAge%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXCATEGORY2%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EDistance%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXCATEGORY1%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EStroke%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3ETIME%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3ETime%2520%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EFINA.POINTS%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EFINA%2520Points%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EFINA.YEAR%24%24SNZ%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EPoints%2520Year%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3E%24DATE%24COMP.DATE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EDate%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EXEVENT.CODE%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3EMeet%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3CColumn%3E%3CField%3EPARAMETER1%3C%2FField%3E%3CColumnName%3ECourse%3C%2FColumnName%3E%3C%2FColumn%3E%3C%2FDownloadColumns%3E"
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'accept-language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Origin': 'https://connect.swimming.org.nz',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Referer': 'https://connect.swimming.org.nz/snz-wrap-public/workflows/COMP.RESULTS.FIND',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=93F2FEA63BA41ECB2505E2D1CD76374D; _ga=GA1.3.1735786808.1620106921; _gid=GA1.3.1806138988.1620106921'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Great, MertG. Thanks. How do I save this data (just the tables) in a .csv/.xlsx format?